# Returning a String value within getItemId method in the Android class BaseAdapter

Tags: android, adapter

I need to return a String value for the following method:

```
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return data.get(i).ID;
    }
```

Example of the previous ID value: 2277.

Example of the new ID value: EATd7ca8a693ac3e422.

Previously, the API I was using had the ID as an int value. 
The API has since changed ID from an int to a String, so this method needs to be fixed so that it can return a String. If I change the method to

```
public String getItem(int i){
```

It says that getItemId clashes with getItemID adapter and that I'm attempting to use an incompatible return type. Is it possible to return a string here? If not, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not parse the int to a string?

```
final String id = Integer.toString(getItemId(int i));

final String id = String.valueOf(getItemId(int i));
```

Or if the returned value is a long

```
final String id = Long.toString(getItemId(int i));
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, but the String ID values from the API look something like "EATb7cc8a693af3c429", whereas before they were previously only contained actual numbers as an int value.